# JavaScript validate then add points on true validation?

Tags: javascript, html, count, validation

I'm writing a website for a school project and I want to have the user type the answer, have JavaScript validate it, and if it's true, add it to a point counter displayed on the top of the page.

How in the world should I go about this?

Is there something in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: you can either: 
1 - wait for your code here.
2 - go here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript & learn javascript and code functionalities you want

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for:

1) [How to access and manipulate the DOM.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_Javascript) You need to manipulate the counter value, for example.

2) How to add event listeners, such as onsubmit/[onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) for your form.

3) [How to do if statements in javascript.](http://www.echoecho.com/javascript6.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it :

1. Put Jquery on your site
2. Add an event listener on the submit field button using Jquery
3. In the jquery, validate the content
4. If the content is validated, then change the counter using Jquery and selector

I can give you more info if you give more info.
Hope this helps though